# Can I Mount an ISO Image Served over FTP / HTTP During the Kickstart %post Process of a RHEL 7 / CentOS 7?

Tags: ftp, httpd, mount, kickstart, iso

I'm attempting to customize a RHEL 7 / CentOS 7 kickstart (ks.cfg) file, which is loaded via PXE booting to mount an ISO file that is accessible via FTP / HTTP.  I understand Busybox tools are available during the kickstart process, and can be added to the %post section of the kickstart file.  I have been unsuccessful in mounting an ISO during this part of the process.  Is this possible?

Comment: What is the purpose of this?

Comment: I want to mount an ISO as a CD-ROM during the %post processing of the kickstart installation.  This is needed  to interact with an existing kickstart script that I inherited (and can not change as this is a standardized baseline I need to test against, without modification) that anticipated being booted from disc as opposed to PXE booting across the network.  The inherited kickstart file checks that the installation media is present as a mounted CD.  I want to make the entire ISO available on the network, so that it can be mounted in lieu of a physical disc. (Yes, this is somewhat convoluted.)

Comment: Hold on. First you say you are customizing the kickstart, and now you say you cannot change it? What is really going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is flawed;
if a script expects to find something on a CD device, mounting the ISO will not necessarily solve your problem.
Moving Disk application to PXE environments takes making applications aware of the "network" option when retrieving components.